# How to set lex slots as contact attributes in amazon connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to set the slot values returned by amazon lex as contact attributes.

[image]

[image]

In order to check whether contact attributes are actually being set, I have invoked a lambda function and printing the event data.

[image]

This is the lambda function.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # TODO implement
    return {}
```

But when i am checking the cloud watch logs i am getting empty strings for `dob` and `ssn`.

```
{
  "Details": {
    "ContactData": {
      "Attributes": {
        "dob": "",
        "ssn": ""
      },
      "Channel": "VOICE",
      "ContactId": "419229f1-44fd-49c5-b382-37229b7a4bc2",
      "CustomerEndpoint": {
        "Address": "+1XXXXXXXXX",
        "Type": "TELEPHONE_NUMBER"
      },
      "CustomerId": null,
      "Description": null,
      "InitialContactId": "419229f1-44fd-49c5-b382-37229b7a4bc2",
      "InitiationMethod": "INBOUND",
      "InstanceARN": "arn:aws:connect:ap-southeast-1:XXXXXXXX:instance/XXXXXXX",
      "LanguageCode": "en-US",
      "MediaStreams": {
        "Customer": {
          "Audio": null
        }
      },
      "Name": null,
      "PreviousContactId": "419229f1-44fd-49c5-b382-37229b7a4bc2",
      "Queue": null,
      "References": {},
      "SystemEndpoint": {
        "Address": "+1XXXXXXXX",
        "Type": "TELEPHONE_NUMBER"
      }
    },
    "Parameters": {}
  },
  "Name": "ContactFlowEvent"
}
```

**P.S: I recited back the slot values in prompt and i am able to hear the correct slot values. But slot values are not getting set as contact attributes.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set contact attributes after invoking lambda function with use attribute as "external" and user defined attribute as destination type.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/attribs-with-lambda.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please use $.Attributes. in the contact flow.
I see you are setting the value in the contact flow as contact attribute as user defined.
$.Attributes.ssn/dob will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).